# Using VS1838B with Arduino

Tags: remote-control, ir

I just bought VS1838B IR module ([from here](http://www.robotistan.com/IR-Alici-Verici-Kumanda-Seti-IR-Receiver-Module-Wireless-Remote-Control-Kit,PR-1788.html)) and I’m trying to make it work. Below you can find the circuit to see how I have connected the 1838B IR receiver:

[image]

My Code ([Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8143467/)) :

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 2;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
#define CH1 0xFFA25D 
#define CH 0xFF629D
#define CH2 0xFFE21D
...
#define BUTON8 0xFF4AB5
#define BUTON9 0xFF52AD

void setup()

{

 Serial.begin(9600);

 irrecv.enableIRIn(); 

}

void loop() {
 

 if (irrecv.decode(&results)) 
  {

 if (results.value == CH1) 

 {

 Serial.println("CH-"); 
 }

 if (results.value == CH) 

 {

 Serial.println("CH"); 

 }

 if (results.value == CH2) 

 {

 Serial.println("CH+"); 

 }

 ...

 if (results.value == BUTON8) 

 {

 Serial.println("BUTON8"); 

 }
if (results.value == BUTON9) 

 {

 Serial.println("BUTON9"); 

 }
 irrecv.resume();

 }

 

}
```

But I'm not getting any output from Serial Monitor.
Can you help me for debugging it?

Comment: Are you sure you have a proper remote control? How did you get the constant values from?

Comment: You should add `Serial.println(results.value);` after `if irrecv.decode(&results)) {` to check what codes are really received from your remote.

Comment: @jfpoilpret It's not printing anything, it's not going inside of that if() . I'm use I'm using a proper controller because all they came together, as a kit.

Answer (score 3):

Looking further here

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,188236.0.h...

I found the following

"Removing 
the files - libraries\RobotIRremote\IRremoteTools.cpp and 
libraries\RobotIRremote\IRremoteTools.h solved the problem. They are
example files which somehow are getting included. You can move those two 
files to some other location as backup."

I went to my libraries 
file and did this and can confirm that the example given above then 
compiles fine without downloading a new library. Its an Arduino 
libraries problem .

Either way will work

[answer from here and worked for me](http://www.instructables.com/id/Remote-Control-Light-switch-ARDUINO/)

i use this code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
int input_pin = 10; //set D10 as input signal pin
IRrecv irrecv(input_pin);
decode_results signals;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    irrecv.enableIRIn(); // enable input from IR receiver
}
void loop() {
if (irrecv.decode(&signals)) {
        Serial.println(signals.value, HEX);
        irrecv.resume(); // get the next signal
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, this was my issue as well. On macOS the files are stored in the contents of `Arduino.app`, so using Finder you need to go to `/Applications`, then right-click `Arduino.app` and click "Show Package Contents". Now, navigate to the folder `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries` and delete the folder "RobotIRremote". You can also do this easily from the Terminal using the `rm -r /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/RobotIRremote` command.

Answer (score 2):

i have also bought this IR receiver with a remote controller (as a kit), and i had the same problem, i changed the remote controller and it worked perfectly, so even if the IR and RC came as a kit it doesn't mean they will work, if you don't have another remote controller in hand you can use a lighter just to check if the IR is working.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I believe that this receiver operates at 38kHz (at least that is listed in the specs), so the IR source must be oscillating at that frequency for this receiver to see it. Check out this link to see how to create a circuit to oscillate your IR LED:

http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/ir-emitter-at-38khz.94119/

Comment: Whilst you link may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the **essential parts of the linked here,** and provide the link for citation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
void loop(void) {
   int numberpulses;

   numberpulses = listenForIR();

   Serial.print("Heard ");
   Serial.print(numberpulses);
   Serial.println("-pulse long IR signal");
   if (IRcompare(numberpulses, ApplePlaySignal)) {
      Serial.println("PLAY");
      if (ledState == LOW)
         ledState = HIGH;
      else
         ledState = LOW;

      // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
      digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState); 

   }
   if (IRcompare(numberpulses, AppleRewindSignal)) {
      Serial.println("REWIND");
   }
   if (IRcompare(numberpulses, AppleForwardSignal)) {
      Serial.println("FORWARD");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

connect vcc to 5V
connect Gnd to GND
connect In to D11 pin onto Uno, Nano etc.
download the library from here and follow the instructions/where to unzip and removing the other folders/:
http://z3t0.github.io/Arduino-IRremote/

Open the Arduino program and paste this code onto a new Arduino project:

```
int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}
void loop()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results))
    {
     Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
     irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
    }
}
```

Select 'Sketch'/Import Library from Arduino and select IRremote from the drop-down menu.

Upload the sketch
Open Tools/Serial monitor then select 9600 as baud rate
Use a Tv remote, IR car remote or the remote from the module.
You will see the HEX code of each button after pressing it.